# Convert excel formula into DAX

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dax, powerpivot, daxstudio

`=COUNTIFS('Incident Data'!$M:$M,"x",'Incident Data'!$G:$G,"Aircraft Damage - Other", 'Incident Data'!$A:$A, ">=1/1/22", 'Incident Data'!$A:$A, "<=1/31/22")`

I look up some example and tried doing it but nothing is working out and hope one you guys can help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
YourMeasure =
  CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('YourTable'),
    'YourTable'[NameOfColumn M] = "x" &&
    'YourTable'[NameOfColumn G] = "Aircraft Damage - Other" &&
    'YourTable'[NameOfColumn A] >= DATE(2022, 1, 1) &&
    'YourTable'[NameOfColumn A] <= DATE(2022, 1, 31)
  )
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?